# How to subset data according to date in R?

Tags: r, date, subset

Simple enough question. I have data of US treasury bill rates, with two columns- 
1) Date and 2) Rate. The data ranges back to 1960. I wish to subset the rates from 1990 onward, i.e. according to the date.

Code:-

```
data = read.csv("3mt-bill.csv")

rates= ?
```

So, I just want a vector of the t-bill rates, but from 1990 onwards. 
How should I write the condition?

Comment: Does the Date column contain only the year? And what does `class(data$Date)` return?

Comment: No, the date's in the format of dd/mm/year. And class(data$Date) returned Null.

Comment: It would help to see the first few rows of your data. The NULL suggests there is no column named Date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to first convert the 'Date' to `Date` class, extract the year with `format`, check whether it is greater than 1990 and subset the 'Rates' based on that logical `vector`

```
data$Rate[format(as.Date(data$Date), "%Y") >= 1990]
```

---

If the 'Date' column include only year part, it is easier

```
data$Rate[data$Date >= 1990]
```

---

Just in case, if we need `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
      filter(year(ymd(Date)) >= 1990) %>%
      select(Rate)
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[year(as.IDate(Date)) >= 1990, Rate]
```